# What valve to use to divert incoming air from a pipe to another pipe stream?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, airflow, valves

There's an 4 inch exhaust stream that's emitting air at 2000CFM, I want to divide the exhaust in a 'Y' kind of outlet with two pipes.

If State 0- Exhaust out through one pipe.

If state 1- Exhaust out through another pipe.

What electrically actuated valves should I look at?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a three way valve.

[image]

They come in a top down (above) and a one plane configuration (below).

[image]

The top down configuration allows L style and T style, while the one plane is typically only L style:

[image]

For your application a one plane configuration should suit you nicely, and is typically cheaper.

Comment: Thanks @mark awesome, looking at http://www.vortexglobal.com/rotary-vs-flapper-vs-blade-style-diverter-valves/  just trying to find what's the best online market place for the same. Also where do you think I can find something that could resist high temperatures. ^_^ Thanks

Comment: @touchaddict interesting site and useful information. As you know a lot goes into selecting piping material for an application and you know your application better than I do. All of that said, in applications I've run across, if a ball valve can handle the application, the three way valve can as well, so long as particle size isn't a major issue. If it is a concern, then filter out the particles before the valve. Or, if  only one of the states is particle generation, consider using the t style and running through a leg (using the left leg for example, then switching between state 2 & 4)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqOplj2HSdE&t=1s this is the application I am trying to build. The input air is sooty carbon loaded, and I am in a rural part of India right now, so component sourcing is a little pain :)

Comment: look at this, https://www.ductingsystems.com/nordfab-parts-automatic-diverter-valve.html 4" valve system costs more than 2000$ crazy. hacks?

Comment: These definitely seem crazy, but are intended for people who want to install them and never touch them again.  My best suggestion then is to look for 3d printing to make a mold, then manufacture your own.

Comment: doing that tomorrow!